# REST API for Query Classification

Tags: rest, classification

I'm trying to find a REST API service which would classify a search query.

E.g.:
For "Albert Einstein" it would return "person", "physicist", "scientist", ...
For "London" it would return "city", "capital city", "city in UK", ...

Wikipedia API is useless in this regard, because the closest thing it returns are the categories for a page which are never granular enough. For example, for Albert Einstein, you get "20th-century physicists", "People from Berlin", but never the basic "person" or "physicist".

Does anyone know of any such service? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean, never granular enough? "20th-century physicists" is more specific than "physicist".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity - "20th-century physicists" is not more granular than ["physicist", "person", "20th-cetury"]

Comment: Right, I see what you mean.